# MySQL 5.5 for windows?

Tags: mysql

Today version 5.5 was released but all the official builds in the mysql website are for linux. does anybody knows when windows downloads for this release will be available?

Comment: That's no release. It's just Milestone 2 and "ready for testing". Quote: "As with any other pre-production set of software, the milestone release of MySQL 5.5 is not recommended for use on production systems."

Comment: or any estimation when the release version is planned for?

Comment: My oracle says: 42 (maybe you should ask your question here: http://forums.mysql.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Download MySQL 5.5 source code.

[http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/BuildingMySQLonWindows](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Building_MySQL_on_Windows)

Answer (score 0):

These instructions are very old, they do not work anymore. http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/CMake is current and describes build everywhere, not only Windows. It does not have pictures and intended audience is techical, but it is kept up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

This step-by-step guide http://sleto.wordpress.com/2010/11/26/step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-compile-mysql-5-5-on-microsoft-windows/ has pictures and absolutely all details (though it is somewhat VC Express specific)

Besides, to the original question, the Windows binaries are there already.